# Arguments to -type should contain only one letter

Tags: windows, bash, find, git-bash

[image]

I'm working in win 10 with git-bash. I have a large group of files all of which have no extension. However I've realized that those of type "File" are html files. To select these I tried:

```
$ find -type "File"
find: Arguments to -type should contain only one letter
```

How would I select files of Type 'File' (regardless of extension)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The types in that column are Windows' best guess at the type of file - this has nothing to do with the UNIX utility `find`:

```
find -type f # find all files
```

Would return everything in your screenshot, as they are all files of some kind.

To match all files without an extension (where an "extension" is defined as three lowercase alphabet characters after a dot), you could use:

```
find -not -name '*.[a-z][a-z][a-z]'
```

Alternatively you could change the pattern to `*.*` to match any file not containing a dot.

You could go for something more complicated if you needed, using a regular expression:

```
find -regextype posix-extended -not -iregex '.*/.+\.[a-z]{1,4}'
```

This matches any files that don't end in a dot followed by between one and four characters.